# Application of Successive differentiation

Tags: real-analysis

**If $P_n=D^n(x^n\log x)$, then prove that $P_n=nP_{n-1}+(n-1)!$. Hence prove that

$P_n=n!(\log x+1+\frac 12+\frac 13+\ldots+\frac 1n)$**

I did the first part.
\begin{align}
P_n &=D^n(x^n\log x)\\
&= D^{n-1}\{D(x^n\log x)\}\\ 
&= D^{n-1}(nx^{n-1}\log x+x^{n-1})\\ 
&= D^{n-1}(nx^{n-1}\log x)+D^{n-1}(x^{n-1})\\
&= nD^{n-1}(x^{n-1}\log x)+(n-1)!\\
&= nP_{n-1}+(n-1)!
\end{align}

I'm having trouble with the substitution that is really needed to prove the later part.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the recurrence formula:

$$P_n = nP_{n-1} + (n-1)!$$

observe that:

$$P_n = n\left[ (n-1)P_{n-2} + (n-2)! \right] + \frac{n!}{n}$$

$$P_n = n(n-1) P_{n-2} + \frac{n!}{n-1} + \frac{n!}{n}$$

$$P_n = n(n-1)\left[ (n-2)P_{n-3} + (n-3)!\right] + \frac{n!}{n-1} + \frac{n!}{n} $$

$$\therefore P_n = n(n-1)(n-2)P_{n-3} + \frac{n!}{n-2} + \frac{n!}{n-1} + \frac{n!}{n}$$

Proceeding as such, we obviously end up with:

$$P_n = n! P_0 + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n!}{k} = n! \left( P_0 + 1 + \frac12 + \cdots + \frac1n \right)$$

and $P_0$ is just $\log x$.